# PHP - Pass parameters throughout deep levels of callback function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel-Excel library to develop an export xls function.
I need to add a value to specific cell. As documentation, I wrote script

```
$data = MyModel::getComplexData();

Excel::create('Export payroll', function($excel) use ($data) {

    $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use ($data) {
        $sheet->cell('A1', function ($cell) use ($data) {
            $cell->setValue($data->name);
        });
    });

})->download('xls');
```

You can see parameter `$data` had been passed 3 times over 3 callback functions.
I need to find a way to make the script more clearly (pass `$data` only 1 time).

Comment: I don't see any other solution since if you use only once then $data variable will be undefined

Comment: This is more clear actually. Future developer will exactly know where the `$data` is coming from. Alternative is to use `$GLOBALS` variable, but I won't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

I have and idea look at the below code. we can set into member varibale.

```
<?php
class Test(){

    private $data = "Hellow";
    public function funct(){
        $data = MyModel::getComplexData();
        $this->data = $data;

        Excel::create('Export payroll', function($excel){

            $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet){
                $sheet->cell('A1', function ($cell){
                    $cell->setValue($this->data->name);
                });
            });

        })->download('xls');
    }
}

?>
```